# Double Periodic Function with a Factor

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z+1)=f(z)$ and $f(z+i)=e^{2\pi}f(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

I "guessed" that such a holomorphic function should be $f(z)=e^{-2\pi iz}$, but don't know how to justify whether this is the only one; can I get some hint on how to proceed?

Comment: *Hint:* What can you say about $g(z)=e^{2\pi iz}f(z)$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Brilliant observation Martin, thank you so much! The function $g$ will be double periodic and entire, thus a constant; so $f=ce^{-2\pi iz}$.